# xpra: client window shows only part of the screen of the server host

Tags: xpra

I am running xpra client on a 14" laptop, and xpra server on a 15" laptop. The xpra client window   on the 14" laptop shows the screen of the 15" laptop only partially (a part near the bottom and a part near the right are cut off). The screenshot below shows the screen of the 14" laptop with the xpra client window inside.

Both laptops are running Lubuntu 18.04.

The remote xpra version and screen dimension and resolution are:

```
$ xpra --version
xpra v3.0.8-r25889

$ xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (508x285 millimeters)
```

The local xpra version and screen dimension and resolution are:

```
$ xpra --version
xpra v3.0.8-r25889

$ xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
  dimensions:    1440x900 pixels (381x238 millimeters)
```

Here is the command that I ran to connect. Do I need to provide more information in the command to solve the problem?

```
$ xpra shadow ssh:"t@onion":0

(xpra:16983): dbind-WARNING **: 20:13:10.163: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
2020-04-07 20:13:10,318 Xpra GTK3 X11 client version 3.0.7-r25627 64-bit
2020-04-07 20:13:10,613  running on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
2020-04-07 20:13:10,615  window manager is 'Openbox'
2020-04-07 20:13:10,697 Warning: failed to import opencv:
2020-04-07 20:13:10,697  No module named 'cv2'
2020-04-07 20:13:10,698  webcam forwarding is disabled

(Xpra-Audio-query:17000): dbind-WARNING **: 20:13:11.757: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
2020-04-07 20:13:11,895 GStreamer version 1.14.5 for Python 3.6.9 64-bit
2020-04-07 20:13:12,374 No OpenGL_accelerate module loaded: No module named 'OpenGL_accelerate'
2020-04-07 20:13:13,002 Error: cannot handle window transparency
2020-04-07 20:13:13,002  screen is not composited
2020-04-07 20:13:13,086 Warning: vendor 'Intel Open Source Technology Center' is greylisted,
2020-04-07 20:13:13,086  you may want to turn off OpenGL if you encounter bugs
2020-04-07 20:13:13,349 Error: cannot handle window transparency
2020-04-07 20:13:13,349  screen is not composited
2020-04-07 20:13:13,360 Warning: window 4294967295 changed its transparency attribute
2020-04-07 20:13:13,361  from False to True, behaviour is undefined
2020-04-07 20:13:13,450 OpenGL enabled with Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
2020-04-07 20:13:13,730 Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.6p1)
2020-04-07 20:13:14,386 loaded RSA private key from '/home/t/.ssh/id_rsa'
2020-04-07 20:13:14,405 Authentication (publickey) successful!
2020-04-07 20:13:14,736  keyboard settings: rules=evdev, model=pc105, layout=us
2020-04-07 20:13:14,834  desktop size is 1440x900 with 1 screen:
2020-04-07 20:13:14,835   :0.0 (381x238 mm - DPI: 96x96) workarea: 1440x876
2020-04-07 20:13:14,835     LVDS-1 (303x190 mm - DPI: 120x120)
2020-04-07 20:13:14,909 no ethtool interface speed available for wlx801f02b5c389
2020-04-07 20:13:20,742 enabled remote logging
2020-04-07 20:13:20,744 Xpra GTK3 shadow server version 3.0.8-r25889 64-bit
2020-04-07 20:13:20,746  running on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
2020-04-07 20:13:21,120 server does not support xi input devices
2020-04-07 20:13:21,123  server uses: auto

(Xpra-Audio-play:17029): dbind-WARNING **: 20:13:22.207: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
2020-04-07 20:13:22,299 sound output using pulseaudio device:
2020-04-07 20:13:22,300 sound output  'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'
2020-04-07 20:13:22,898 sound output using 'opus' audio codec
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--desktop-scaling` option to downscale the server's window, you can also change this at runtime from the systray menu.